# jQuery UI, Drag and Drop is not functioning properly if helper option is set to "clone"

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

when a draggable item's helper property is "clone" and then when dropped, its not working.
check the sample code below:

```
    <div  id="clonedDraggableItem" <img src="img\select.png"/></div>
    <div  id="originalDraggableItem" <img src="img\select.png"/></div>

<div id="droppableWorkArea" style="border:1px solid gray; height:475px;width:100px"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#clonedDraggableItem").draggable({opacity: 0.7,helper: "clone"});   
        $("#originalDraggableItem").draggable({opacity: 0.7, helper: "original" });    

        $("#droppableWorkArea").droppable({
            drop: function () {
            }
        });
    });
```

But as you can see, the other item which is not cloned but instead it's "helper" property is set ot "original", then it works. Also that dropped item can be moved across the droppable div.

Please Note: i want the draggable item (with "clone" propery) to not just be dropped, but also to be able to move across the droppable div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it.

```
$( "#draggable" ).draggable({
            helper : "clone"
});
$( "body" ).droppable({
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
        $(ui.helper).removeClass('ui-draggable-dragging');
        var newDiv = $(ui.helper).clone().removeClass('ui-draggable-dragging');
        $(this).append(newDiv);
  }  
});
```

The following examples come from another similar question I answered.

http://jsfiddle.net/Jje3H/

And if you want to make subsequent clones draggable as well then take a look at this example.

http://jsfiddle.net/Jje3H/1/

Or if you just want to be able to move subsequent clones then:

http://jsfiddle.net/Jje3H/2/

Comment: Thanks folk, this helped me a lot. Thank once again. :)

Comment: great answer Trevor. keep rocking